# Speed of MySQL connection vs PHP file access

Tags: php, mysql, performance, file-io

Assume that I have a simple VPS setup with LAMP (so with PHP and MySQL on the same server and no other strings attached). And assume that I want to make a self-written ajax chat client on my website.

Obviously, each participant in the conversation would have to listen constantly for new things being said. Since it is very well possible that two or more participants say something in the very same second (and refreshing more than once per second would likely cause insane system load), it seems to me that I would need to store for each participant a list of things that happened since the last refresh.

Which would be the "best" way to do this (in terms of system load)? In the following, an "event" just 'any participant saying anything in the chat'. Clearly, this could be used for a more general as well.

(A) Use MySQL, connecting to the db every second and asking for events WHERE participant_id = $participant_id? (and then deleting all of these so they're only fetched once)

(B) Create a file $participant_id.php and append the events to it (in PHP format  so that it can be included, and then empty or delete the file at the next refresh?

(C) Does anyone know any other useful alternatives?

Comment: storing the last x seconds of text in memory seems viable. You could still log the text to mysql, but you wouldn't need to ask mysql for it back under normal circumstances because everything needed is either in memory, or has been sent to the client.

Comment: Before I answer, have you considered using a message queue?

Comment: @Chris: how can I store these in RAM in PHP? Or would you recommend other, non-php means for this?

Comment: @Xepoch: I had not considered message queue, I will have a read on these message queues. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Do you have a need to save the chat for later use? Otherwise, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use a socket connection. Each person connected to the socket server daemon would be able to send a message to the daemon, the daemon would then send the message out to all or a partial list of subscribers which makes chat instantaneous with no need to save the data at all.

A good way to create socket connections from a client is socket IO. See below.

http://socket.io/

A good technology to use for creating a socket server daemon is node.js. This is a server side event driven javascript based library. Very efficient for things like this. See below.

http://nodejs.org/

Comment: That sounds very interesting and weird at the same time. I will have a good read on this mechanic. Also, is it really impossible to log the chat in this way (assuming people don't hack the client, that is)?

Comment: @user1111929 What do you mean exactly by "log" the chat? You want to save it all on the server for later use?

Comment: It would be a benefit, yes. Not only for the chat example, but I would be using this system also for small multiplayer games (checkers, blackjack, uno, ...) and there it may be useful to debug an app should it crash, or to catch cheaters. But this is not a major issue.

Comment: @user1111929 you could log everything at the same time you send it out to subscribers using this method. node.js allows for flat file writing as well as DB connections. an alternative would be to have a debug client connected to the socket server at all times which receives all messages, and you could use that for logging. this way you do not mix your debug code with your production code, and would probably be faster performance.

Answer (score 1):

On both A and B you are still effectively polling.  You will either poll MySQL which really isn't too bad, or you can get notified on `select()` of a file change BUT you will still need to parse to see if the new data is the right stuff on the file-side.

For conceptual and support ease-of-use, it is really hard to beat a database as you won't have to worry about locking semantics.  Debugging and message tracking are clean in this structure.

I however recommend you investigate the `msg_send()` and `msg_receive()` (of PHP) functions to put this data into an underlying message queue.  Your problem seems to be a message queueing problem that should be solved by that mechanism.

Comment: Actually, in (B) I only need a file_exists, right? This should be very cheap in terms of resources. But msg_receive() is still a better way if I understand correctly? What I am mainly worried about is that users leaving the chat/game/... unexpectedly, would cause their message queue to persist forever. For the files, I can delete the old files manually every week, based on their timestamp, but I cannot seem to find anyhere how to do this for the message queues...

Comment: You can setup multiple queues and remove the queue if no activity.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-remove-queue.php  You can also find out the time of the last messages through stat'ing the queue http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.msg-stat-queue.php

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know any other useful alternatives?

If you search simple solutions on PHP, I can offer 2 ways:

**Cache**

It mean that you keep MySQL for store data, but install APC (this solution is simplest and fastest for small servers and applications) or Memcached (better for using width several servers). For each read-request you check APC/Memcached for you data and ask MySQL only if your cache is removed or updated. And on each write-request you inserting data in MySQL and update cache.

**Other DB**

In this case you change MySQL for one of memory-base DB (for example MongoDB). And you may not afraid hard disk usage.